# Error message with Krige function: Error in as.character.default(X[[i]], ...) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Tags: r, sf, sp, kriging, gstat

I am trying to run the Krige function but I keep receiving NA values for var1.pred and var1.var. After using the warning() command, it says: Error in as.character.default(X[[i]], ...) :
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Is there an obvious error I am making here? This is my first semester using R code so my skill level is definitely subpar...

My code is:

```
> library(geoR)
> library(gstat)
> library(sp)
> library(sf)
> library(raster)
> 
> mydata <- read.csv('CA PM2.5.csv')
> mydata.sf = st_as_sf( mydata , coords=c('LON','LAT'))
> mydata.sf=st_set_crs(mydata.sf,'WGS84')
> mydata.sp <- as(mydata.sf, Class = "Spatial")
> 
> V=variogram(Z~1, data=mydata.sf, cutoff = 300)
> plot(V)
> 
> VModel <- vgm(psill=10, model="Sph", nugget=5, range=80)
> plot(V, model=VModel)
> 
> FittedModel <- fit.variogram(V, model=VModel)    
> plot(V, model=FittedModel)
> 
> xgrid <- seq(min(-122.8183),max(-115.4831),by = 0.14492753623)
> ygrid <- seq(min(32.57816),max(41.72689),by = 0.14492753623)
> basexy <- expand.grid(xgrid, ygrid)
> colnames(basexy) <- c("x", "y")
> coordinates(basexy) <- ~x+y
> gridded(basexy) <- TRUE
> proj4string(basexy) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
> plot(basexy)
> basexy.sp=spTransform(basexy,crs(mydata.sp))
> 
> OK_Z = krige(Z~1,mydata.sp,basexy.sp, model = VModel)
[using ordinary kriging]
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> 
> OK_Z
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 3264 
extent      : -122.8183, -115.5719, 32.57816, 41.70859  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 2
names       : var1.pred, var1.var 
min values  :        NA,       NA 
max values  :        NA,       NA 
> plot(OK_Z)
> warning()
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2:  
> 
> ?warning()
> warning(OK_Z)
Error in as.character.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It looks like I had duplicate coordinate points in my data. Once I removed the duplicates it worked for me.